# Python lxml not picking up tags

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, lxml

Hi I am trying to web scrape the CNN Primary Results this election season and do some machine learning with it. I'm using Python 3.5 and so after researching a bit, I saw I can use lxml and BeautifulSoup along with requests to do it. After failing with BeautifulSoup (I tried using XPath but it didn't pick it up), I tried using lxml. In the Iowa Primary Page (and every state so far), CNN breaks it down according to county and percentage of votes for each candidate. After looking into the html page, I saw that each county name is stored such that a county name is part of an h2 tag right after a div tag (along with class attributes) and so on for each county. Thus, I used CSSSelector to try and capture (as h2 always comes after div for a county). The html section looks like this:

```
<div class="race-results__county-header race-results__county-name section-header__column" data-reactid=".0.4.3.0.0.0.0.$0.0.$0">
    <h2 class="section-heading" data-reactid=".0.4.3.0.0.0.0.$0.0.$0.0">Adair</h2>
</div>
```

And the code looks like this:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('http://www.cnn.com/election/primaries/counties/ia/Rep').text
doc = html.fromstring(page)
link = doc.cssselect("div h2")
print(link)
```

However, when I try to print the link, there is absolutely nothing (just an empty array []). Is this a problem with how the html is laid out, the code, or the parser? I'm using PyCharm from JetBeans but I don't think that has anything to do with it. I'm fairly new to this stuff so any other methods would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that the page does not contain the results you expect as they are probably rendered by means of JavaScript.

When I downloaded content from given url, there was no `<h2>` element, but I have found there a message: **Please enable JavaScript to view CNN's 2016 Election Center.**

You are not getting the data as they are not present on the page.

Do not be confused by the fact, your browser might show you the `<h2>` elements - that is because JavaScript has put it into it.

**Hint**: check, what JSON files is the page loading. It is likely, some of the files will provide data readily available for your task. Using F12 in my web browser (and refreshing the page after that) I saw many JSON files present, some of them providing data about candidates.

E.g. url: http://data.cnn.com/ELECTION/2016primary/candidates/can1187.json return following content (shortened):

```
{
  "candidateInfo": {
    "id": 1187,
    "fname": "Mike",
    "lname": "Huckabee",
    "party": "Rep",
    "rd": "1",
    "pd": "0",
    "td": "1",
    "d_nom": 1237,
    "inrace": true,
    "nominee": false,
    "rd_k": "1460",
    "td_k": 2472,
    "dpct": 0,
    "dpct_nom": 50,
    "states": [
      {
        "state": "Alabama",
        "code": "AL",
        "electiondate": "20160301",
        "primarytype": "primary",
        "candidates": []
      },
      {
        "state": "Alaska",
        "code": "AK",
        "electiondate": "20160301",
        "primarytype": "caucus",
        "candidates": []
      },
      {
        "state": "Arizona",
        "code": "AZ",
        "electiondate": "",
        "primarytype": "",
        "candidates": []
      },
      {
        "state": "Arkansas",
        "code": "AR",
        "electiondate": "20160301",
        "primarytype": "primary",
        "candidates": []
      },
      {
        "state": "Iowa",
        "code": "IA",
        "electiondate": "20160201",
        "primarytype": "caucus",
        "candidates": [
          {
            "id": 1187,
            "rd": "1",
            "pd": "0",
            "td": "1",
            "winner": false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "state": "Kansas",
        "code": "KS",
        "electiondate": "20160305",
        "primarytype": "caucus",
        "candidates": []
      },
      {
        "state": "Kentucky",
        "code": "KY",
        "electiondate": "20160305",
        "primarytype": "caucus",
        "candidates": []
      },
      {
        "state": "Louisiana",
        "code": "LA",
        "electiondate": "20160305",
        "primarytype": "primary",
        "candidates": []
      },
      {
        "state": "Maine",
        "code": "ME",
        "electiondate": "20160305",
        "primarytype": "caucus",
        "candidates": []
      },
      {
        "state": "Maryland",
        "code": "MD",
        "electiondate": "",
        "primarytype": "",
        "candidates": []
      },
      {
        "state": "Massachusetts",
        "code": "MA",
        "electiondate": "20160301",
        "primarytype": "primary",
        "candidates": []
      },
      {
        "state": "Michigan",
        "code": "MI",
        "electiondate": "20160308",
        "primarytype": "primary",
        "candidates": []
      },
      {
        "state": "Minnesota",
        "code": "MN",
        "electiondate": "20160301",
        "primarytype": "caucus",
        "candidates": []
      },
      {
        "state": "Mississippi",
        "code": "MS",
        "electiondate": "20160308",
        "primarytype": "primary",
        "candidates": []
      },
      {
        "state": "Missouri",
        "code": "MO",
        "electiondate": "20160315",
        "primarytype": "primary",
        "candidates": []
      },
      {
        "state": "Montana",
        "code": "MT",
        "electiondate": "",
        "primarytype": "",
        "candidates": []
      },
      {
        "state": "Nebraska",
        "code": "NE",
        "electiondate": "",
        "primarytype": "",
        "candidates": []
      },
      {
        "state": "Nevada",
        "code": "NV",
        "electiondate": "20160223",
        "primarytype": "caucus",
        "candidates": []
      },
      {
        "state": "New Hampshire",
        "code": "NH",
        "electiondate": "20160209",
        "primarytype": "primary",
        "candidates": []
      },
      {
        "state": "New Jersey",
        "code": "NJ",
        "electiondate": "",
        "primarytype": "",
        "candidates": []
      },
      {
        "state": "New Mexico",
        "code": "NM",
        "electiondate": "",
        "primarytype": "",
        "candidates": []
      },
      {
        "state": "New York",
        "code": "NY",
        "electiondate": "",
        "primarytype": "",
        "candidates": []
      },
      {
        "state": "North Carolina",
        "code": "NC",
        "electiondate": "20160315",
        "primarytype": "primary",
        "candidates": []
      },
      {
        "state": "North Dakota",
        "code": "ND",
        "electiondate": "",
        "primarytype": "",
        "candidates": []
      },
      {
        "state": "Ohio",
        "code": "OH",
        "electiondate": "20160315",
        "primarytype": "primary",
        "candidates": []
      },
      {
        "state": "Oklahoma",
        "code": "OK",
        "electiondate": "20160301",
        "primarytype": "primary",
        "candidates": []
      },
      {
        "state": "Oregon",
        "code": "OR",
        "electiondate": "",
        "primarytype": "",
        "candidates": []
      },
      {
        "state": "Virgin Islands",
        "code": "VI",
        "electiondate": "",
        "primarytype": "",
        "candidates": []
      },
      {
        "state": "Northern Marianas",
        "code": "MP",
        "electiondate": "",
        "primarytype": "",
        "candidates": []
      }
    ],
    "races": [
      {
        "status": "called",
        "code": "AR",
        "state": "Arkansas",
        "polltype": "exit",
        "primarytype": "primary",
        "cresults": true,
        "cmap": true,
        "xpoll": true,
        "electiondate": "20160301",
        "pctsrep": 100,
        "ts": 1457130949809,
        "racerank": 6,
        "winner": false,
        "vpct": 1,
        "pctDecimal": "1.2",
        "inc": false,
        "votes": 4703,
        "cvotes": "4,703",
        "rd": "0",
        "pd": "0",
        "sd": "0",
        "td": "0",
        "position": 13
      },
      {
        "status": "called",
        "code": "GA",
        "state": "Georgia",
        "polltype": "exit",
        "primarytype": "primary",
        "cresults": true,
        "cmap": true,
        "xpoll": true,
        "electiondate": "20160301",
        "pctsrep": 92,
        "ts": 1457130978961,
        "racerank": 8,
        "winner": false,
        "vpct": 0,
        "pctDecimal": "0.2",
        "inc": false,
        "votes": 2615,
        "cvotes": "2,615",
        "rd": "0",
        "pd": "0",
        "sd": "0",
        "td": "0",
        "position": 13
      },
      {
        "status": "called",
        "code": "TN",
        "state": "Tennessee",
        "polltype": "exit",
        "primarytype": "primary",
        "cresults": true,
        "cmap": true,
        "xpoll": true,
        "electiondate": "20160301",
        "pctsrep": 100,
        "ts": 1457131086792,
        "racerank": 7,
        "winner": false,
        "vpct": 0,
        "pctDecimal": "0.3",
        "inc": false,
        "votes": 2404,
        "cvotes": "2,404",
        "rd": "0",
        "pd": "0",
        "sd": "0",
        "td": "0",
        "position": 15
      },
      {
        "status": "called",
        "code": "IA",
        "state": "Iowa",
        "polltype": "entrance",
        "primarytype": "caucus",
        "cresults": true,
        "cmap": true,
        "xpoll": true,
        "electiondate": "20160201",
        "pctsrep": 99,
        "ts": 1454997428611,
        "racerank": 9,
        "winner": false,
        "vpct": 2,
        "pctDecimal": "1.8",
        "inc": false,
        "votes": 3345,
        "cvotes": "3,345",
        "rd": "1",
        "pd": "0",
        "sd": "1",
        "td": "1",
        "position": 14
      },
      {
        "status": "called",
        "code": "AL",
        "state": "Alabama",
        "polltype": "exit",
        "primarytype": "primary",
        "cresults": true,
        "cmap": true,
        "xpoll": true,
        "electiondate": "20160301",
        "pctsrep": 100,
        "ts": 1456958822650,
        "racerank": 8,
        "winner": false,
        "vpct": 0,
        "pctDecimal": "0.3",
        "inc": false,
        "votes": 2535,
        "cvotes": "2,535",
        "rd": "0",
        "pd": "0",
        "sd": "0",
        "td": "0",
        "position": 13
      }
    ],
    "lts": 1458233488340
  }
}
```